# Java application with Apache Livy

Tags: livy

I decided to build a web service(app) for Apache Spark with Apache Livy.
Livy server is up and running on localhost port 8998 according to Livy configuration defaults.
My test program is a sample application in Apache Livy documentation:  https://livy.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/programmatic-api.html

While creating LivyClient by **LivyClientBuilder** class,

```
 client = new LivyClientBuilder().setURI(new 
 URI("http","user:info","localhost",8998,"","",""))
    .build();
```

I got "URI is not supported by any registered client factories" exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI 'http://%5Bredacted%5D@localhost:8998?#' is not supported by any registered client factories.
at org.apache.livy.LivyClientBuilder.build(LivyClientBuilder.java:155)
at Client.<init>(Client.java:17)
at Client.main(Client.java:25)
```

I found out client instance stays null in **LivyClientBuilder** class.

```
client = factory.createClient(uri, this.config);
```

factory is an instance of **LivyClientFactory** interface.
The only class which implements the interface is **RSCClientFactory**.
  In **RSCClientFactory** we have this piece of code:

```
if (!"rsc".equals(uri.getScheme())) {
     return null;
 }
```

I've tried "rsc" instead of "http", this is the error:

```
    2018-09-15 11:32:55 ERROR RSCClient:340 - RPC error.
  java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Client closed before SASL negotiation finished.
  javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Client closed before SASL negotiation finished.
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:41)
    at org.apache.livy.rsc.rpc.Rpc$SaslClientHandler.dispose(Rpc.java:419)
    at org.apache.livy.rsc.JobHandleImpl.get(JobHandleImpl.java:60)
    at org.apache.livy.rsc.rpc.SaslHandler.channelInactive(SaslHandler.java:92)
    at Client.main(Client.java:39)
```

Apache Livy is running on  http://localhost:8998 then I think we need submit our jar file to this address, but I don't understand "rsc" there.

I would appreciate if anyone guides me about these problems.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass your URL as a String:

```
LivyClient client = new LivyClientBuilder()
                .setURI(new URI("http://localhost:8998"))
                .build();
```

After that you can add your *.jar file with:

```
client.addJar("file://...yourPathToJarHere.../*.jar");
```

or

```
client.uploadJar(new File("...."));
```

It depends on your cluster configuration. You can find full java API description here: https://livy.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your help,
I did those things but resetting all the project helped,
probably the problem was the machine configuration.  

But in general, I think Livy has sparse documentation.

Comment: how do I set spark master programatically using Livy client?

Answer (score 0):

> The only class which implements the interface is RSCClientFactory.

Just add `livy-client-http` to your classpath.

https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/blob/412ccc8fcf96854fedbe76af8e5a6fec2c542d25/client-http/src/main/java/org/apache/livy/client/http/HttpClientFactory.java#L29

https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/blob/56c76bc2d4563593edce062a563603fe63e5a431/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/livy/examples/PiApp.java#L79

Docs: https://livy.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/programmatic-api.html